# Employing inheritance with JavaScript Function objects

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Is it possible to make two or more JavaScript function objects that inherit properties from a common object?

```
var obj common = {
    a: 'first',
    b: 'second',
    z: 'last'
};

var foo = function() {};
var bar = function() {};

// Some magic occurs here

foo.a; // 'first'
bar.z; // 'last'
```

One way to do this would be to employ a mixin, where we iterate through common and copy the properties over to foo and bar. However, if we have a huge list of properties, this could become inefficient.

Is there a more JavaScript way of doing this? I would love to use the prototype chain here, but I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do exactly what you want,but I don't think you want what you think you want. If you know what I mean?!

This requires modern Chrome or FF:

```
var common = {
    __proto__: Function.prototype,
    a: 'first',
    b: 'second',
    z: 'last'
};

var foo = function() {};
var bar = function() {};

Object.setPrototypeOf(foo, common);
Object.setPrototypeOf(bar, common);

console.log(foo.a); // 'first'
console.log(bar.z); // 'last'
```

I think what you want is this:

```
var common = {      
  a: 'first',
  b: 'second',
  z: 'last'
};

var Foo = function() {};
var Bar = function() {};

Foo.prototype = Bar.prototype = common;

var foo = new Foo();
var bar=  new Bar();

console.log(foo.a); // 'first'
console.log(bar.z); // 'last'
```

Comment: No, I specifically want to create objects that inherit from a common parent prototype, but that can also be applied to arguments as a function. Thank you!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's not generally a good idea to directly set proto. Could this be done instead by an extra call to Object.setPrototypeOf(common, Function.prototype)?

Comment: Also, it looks like setPrototypeOf is not supported in Safari.

Comment: The former approach in my answer is going against the grain of the language, hence it is using mess widely supported constructs/methods. The latter approach is the more conventional, leveraging the prototype chain.

Comment: That's true; but they accomplish different goals. Your second approach sets up the prototype chain for instances of the function object, whereas I want to set up the prototype chain of the function object itself. Seems like the Javascript writers didn't intend for programmers to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to create functions in ways other than:

- `function foo (){ }` (function declaration)
- the `Function` constructor
- `var foo = function(){ }` (function expressions)
- `() => {}` (ES6 arrows).

In all of these, you can't specify a base class for the function itself. Like you noted however, a mixin like trick would work here just fine.

Note, in advance one might think that the following might work:

```
function f(){
   return Function.apply(this, arguments);
}
f.prototype = Object.create(Function.prototype);
f.x = 15;
```

But it doesn't, and it doesn't either according to the spec (namely, because the function constructor called as a function behaves the same - i.e. it ignores `this` passed in).